# how to hide/ show custom toolbar(s) in a subclass of uiimage picker controller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I subclassed uiimagepickercontroller for a camera based application, and added two custom tool bars.I want to navigate to another viewcontroller before taking a photo and  the custom tool bars hidden in the new view.Till here it is working fine.But when i pop back to camera view controller,the tool bars are still hidden.Where exactly should i write the code to unhide the toolbars?? I wrote the code to unhide in viewWillAppear method of camera class.But it is not working

Answer (score 0):

it is correct to write the code under viewWillAppear, but it should be in the viewController (UIViewController)

Comment: That is how i did it..but viewWillAppear is not called when i pop back to camera view controller